# Find the equation of the plane through a point which is perpendicular to a curve

Tags: surfaces

Find the equation of the plane through the point $(1, -1, 2)$ which is perpendicular
to the curve of intersection of the two surfaces
$x^2 + y^2 - z = 0$ and $2x^2 + 3y^2 + z^2 - 9 = 0$.

And would you be able to explain the steps? thanks!

Comment: It's literally the exact same as how I was given the question. Would you be able to elaborate?

Comment: No? It's question one of this paper if that's any easier though https://www.mis.nuigalway.ie/papers_public/2013_2014/MA/2013_2014_MA2101_1_1_5.PDF

Comment: yeah, that's better, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we need to find the tangent vector to the curve. We can solve the first equation for $z$ to get
$$z=x^2+y^2$$
Plug this into the second equation to get that the curve satisfies
$$2x^2+3y^2+x^4+2x^2y^2+y^4-9=0$$
Use implicit differentiation to obtain an equation for $\frac{dy}{dx}$ and plug in the coordinates for the point. Solve to get that
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=2$$
Hence
$$\frac{dz}{dx}=2x+2y \frac{dy}{dx}=2-4= -2$$
And a tangent vector is
$$(1,2,-2)$$
The plane is orthogonal to this and passes through $(1,-1,2)$, hence it is given by
$$(x-1)+2(y+1)-2(z-2)=0$$

Comment: Why is dz/dx = -2 ?

Comment: @Ryan please see edit above.